# Speed up call to secret manager in bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, caching

I have a bash script in each environment that with it I set up all the env variables before each script. Recently changed the script and added a python script that gets a list of aws secrets and store them in env variables. So in `env.sh` instead of:

```
pass=1234
```

now I have:

```
pass=$(get-key.py dev/pass)
```

`get-key.py` (which was based of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_secrets-manager_code_examples.html)) runs in about 0.4s which make all my scripts 0.4s slower (and much more if it is a script calling a script etc...). I'm open to hear how can I make `env.sh` faster while keeping security, caching is one thing that comes into mind. Not sure how though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you set and export it (and your other common environment variables) in your .profile (or .bash_profile or .bashrc) instead of setting it in every script? That's kinda the point of your .profile - to set your common environment variables in one place so you don't have to waste time/code doing it in your scripts.

Otherwise, if you wanted to cache it then something like this (untested) in your .bashrc:

```
get_pass() {
    local pass cache="$HOME/.pass"
    [[ -s "$cache" ]] && pass=$(< "$cache")
    [[ -z "$pass" ]] && pass=$(get-key.py dev/pass)
    if [[ -n "$pass" ]]; then
        printf '%s' "$pass" > "$cache"
        printf '%s' "$pass"
    fi
}
```

and then this in your scripts:

```
pass=$( get_pass )
```

or if it might already be set:

```
[[ -z "$pass" ]] && pass=$( get_pass )
```

might do what you want.

If you do decide to set and export it in your .profile or similar then make sure to change it to all upper case.

Comment: Thanks. But does `export` or store pass into file secure?

Comment: Depends what it is, where you store it, etc. I'm not familiar with "AWS secrets" but, for example, your ssh private keys are stored in a human-readable way in a file, e.g. `~/.ssh/id-rsa`, so storing something in a file doesn't by itself mean it's a bad thing. You'd have to read up on "AWS secrets" to learn the dos/don'ts about them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an associative array to store secrets :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A secrets_assoc_array
get-key(){
    local key=$1
    declare -n global_variable=$2
    if  test -v secrets_assoc_array[key]; then
        echo "DEBUG: the password for key [$key] is in cache." >&2
    else
        echo "DEBUG: the password for key [$key] is not in cache." >&2
        secrets_assoc_array[key]="$(get-key.py "$key")"
    fi
    global_variable="${secrets_assoc_array[key]}"
}

get-key dev/pass pass
echo "pass=$pass"
get-key dev/pass pass
echo "pass=$pass"
```